# onListItemClickListener: passing the long id value

Tags: android, database, sqlite, onitemclicklistener

### UPDATE

The original question i asked was about my long id value but because you guys were right in the way u said i had the correct id i removed my error. Thanks for the help. read my answer for more detail.

1) My app uses the local android SQLiteDatabase and has three tables. I have no problems for two of the tables but turns out my third one is presenting some issues because of my column declarations are `public static final string COLUMN_NAME = "name";` ,etc.

My Activities are not extending the ListActivity so that I can have custom lists and listviews for each activity.

I am getting my listview by `listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);` and adding a listener to the listview by `listview.setOnItemClickListener(ListListener);` Then here is my method for the list listener:

```
 OnItemClickListener ListListener = new OnItemClickListener(){

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
            final long id)
{
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ExerciseList.this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.edit)
        .setTitle("Update Selected Exercise")
        .setMessage("Would you like to update the current Exercise? Click continue to proceed.")
        .setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                final Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AddExercise.class);
                i.putExtra(ExerciseDbAdapter.KEY_ROW_ID, id);
                startActivityForResult(i, EDIT_EXERCISE);

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });
        dialog.show();  
    }
};
```

This above method is just a working on list item click listener!

Comment: Are you saying that the `id` is `null` in the next activity?

Comment: @inner_class7 are you sure that id you put into intent is not null. I tried the same code you have written and it works fine

Comment: really? so you think the issue is somewhere else? this is how I am referring to the id in my new intent `// if the row is not empty initiate the row id to the current row
  mRowId = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState
    .getLong(ExerciseDbAdapter.KEY_ROW_ID) : null;`

Comment: 09-13 09:35:30.910: D/WO_NAME(29171): Workout 1
09-13 09:35:30.940: D/tag1(29171): Now in the on Pause method.
09-13 09:35:30.990: D/FETCH(29171): Retrieving exercises for : Workout 1
09-13 09:35:31.000: D/CURSOR_COUNT(29171): Count is : 1
09-13 09:35:34.370: D/tag2(29171): Now in the on Resume method.
09-13 09:35:34.370: D/mRowId(29171): mRowid = null
this is my logcat output where i am getting the null

Comment: how did you check if the id is null using the `log.d("ID_TAG", "id is :" + id); `

Answer (score 0):

```
  Intent.putExtra("Key",value) is right way to put the data in intent so 

   i.putExtra("INSERT THE KEY HERE",ExerciseDbAdapter.KEY_ROW_ID, id);
```

Comment: this gives me another error still, the final long id is more of an issue then actually receiving the extra in the new intent.

Comment: since you have change  long id to final long id , this may be problem. one way is to define a class long variable and assign the id to this variable and use this in alert dialog on click method

Comment: this is what I am referring to. this `final long id` is giving me the problem. I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: define a long type class variable.let say long xyz;and onItemClick{ xyz= id; and after that use it like this  i.putExtra(ExerciseDbAdapter.KEY_ROW_ID, xyz);

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys so i found the issue with my application and you were all right. I was getting the correct row id from the application.

I however was passing another data member through my intent causing the `setRowIdFromIntent()` method to change the id from `null` to `0`. or from not `null` to `0`.

Basically no matter what the value i was passing it was being set to `0` from my `setRowIdFromIntent()` method because of the data member i passed through. Therefore the above code is almost irrelevant to my problem.

So if you want a working on click list listener the one above will definitely help you pass the correct id to your new activity. Sorry again for this confusion I had on my side. Thanks again for all other postings!